# How can I escape the the double quoted xml in AMPscript

Tags: ampscript, xml, compile-error

After I use http call to get xml from an endpoint, i got this xml;

```
"<root><listing bedrooms="3" bathrooms="2.0" /><listing bedrooms="" bathrooms=""/></root>"
```

However, this xml cannot be parsed by ampscript.
This is what i used in order to parse:

```
    %%[
set @xml = "<root><listing bedrooms="3" bathrooms="2.0" /><listing bedrooms="" bathrooms=""/></root>"
 set @rows = BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, '//listing', 1)
 set @row = Row(@rows, 1)
 set @foo = Field(@row, 'Value')
 set @bedrooms = Field(@row, 'bedrooms_att')
 set @bathrooms = Field(@row, 'bathrooms_att')
]%% 
%%=v(@bedrooms)=%%
```

The error poped out:
`Invalid index (parameter 2) passed to Row function. Index must be less than or equal to the row count. Index Value: 1 Row Count: 0 Function: Row(@rows, 1)`

The issue is the most outside quote, how can i switch it to single quote? or delete that quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use single quotes around your XML, so:

```
set @xml = '<root><listing bedrooms="3" bathrooms="2.0" /><listing bedrooms="" bathrooms=""/></root>'
```

Or you can use use two double-quotes, so:

```
set @xml = "<root><listing bedrooms=""3"" bathrooms=""2.0"" /><listing bedrooms="""" bathrooms=""""/></root>"
```